# elfinder image thumbnails does not show in windows and linux server

Tags: php, linux, elfinder

I test elfinder on **windows localhost** and on a **linux** server but while thumbnail image has created in .tmb folder but has no preview on the **[elFinder](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder)** instances.

this is a screenshot of my elfinder dialog window:
[image]

I test 755 , 775 permissions for .tmb folder on the linux server but the problem is not resolved.

what is problem and haw can I solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [nao-pon Answer](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/issues/1265#issuecomment-196783557), This is by design of [moono theme](https://github.com/lokothodida/elfinder-theme-moono) that I used for change Style of elFinder.

Just need to change this line in theme css file.
theme.css L.54

```
.elfinder-cwd-icon {
  /*
  background-image: none !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  */
}
```

AND
theme.css L.111

```
    .elfinder-cwd-icon-image:before,
.elfinder-cwd-icon-vnd-adobe-photoshop:before,
.elfinder-cwd-icon-postscript:before {
  /*content: '\f1c5';*/
}
```